# Open View from didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this question asked few times and I have tried a few different methods but have not been successful.

The latest method I have tried is as followed : 
I included the ViewController that I wanted to show.  I then put this code in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

```
    CarFinderViewController *pvc = [[CarFinderViewController alloc] init];
   // [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:pvc animated:NO];
```

This did not work. I think the problem I may be having is that my initial view is not a navigation controller like a lot of the examples show.

[image]

This is a picture of my story board> The VC that I want to send the user to is the car finder (bottom right)

Can someone explain to me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You could use basically postNotification when you receive the Remote Notification
for exmaple in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` post notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

now in your `FirstViewController`'s  you can register the FirstViewController for this notification like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushNotificationReceived) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];
```

and in your method

```
-(void)pushNotificationReceived{

CarFinderViewController *pvc = [[CarFinderViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

don't forget to remove the observer from notification in your `dealloc` method

```
-(void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Nah that gives me an error :/ 

-[FirstViewController visibleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd8e590

Comment: what is FirstViewController?

Comment: FirstViewController is the initial view of my app

Comment: it wont work that way, because you should use `visibleViewController` with `NavigationController`

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this without a Navigation controller

Comment: did it solve your problem? it is working solution actually, tested in my apps

Comment: Ah this has run the method in the first view now. Now I need it to get to the next view

Comment: yes but in the method i showed how you can go to next view within the method, just present the 2nd viewcontroller, did you follow the code which i have added?

Comment: Yeah I was testing it part by part. I have added the code to present the second controller and am getting this warning Warning: Attempt to present <CarFinderViewController: 0x1e872680> on <FirstViewController: 0x1d58ad00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Do I need go to the tabBarController then to the CarFinder?

Comment: it depends on your senario, you know which view is opening first when your application starts?  you will have to implement the code in that controller, if your root controller is your tabController then anyways TabController might have some item which will be currentItem.

Comment: this is also missing how to get the user info from the pushNotificationReceived method.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution would be to show the `CarFinderViewController` as a modal view instead of trying to push it to a navigation controller which may or may not be visible at the time.

Another important point to avoid further inconsistencies I'd recommend you instantiate your `CarFinderViewController` from the storyboard instead of directly through the class methods.

Something like:

```
UIViewController * vc = self.window.rootViewController;
// You need to set the identifier from the Interface
// Builder for the following line to work
CarFinderViewController *pvc = [vc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CarFinderViewController"];
[vc presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this and got the following warning Warning: Attempt to present <CarFinderViewController: 0x1e0b9660> on <FirstViewController: 0x1cda7e60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! how can I add it to the hierarchy?

Comment: This really depends on your view hierarchy. As far as I can tell from your storyboard you have a main tab controller. You can keep a reference to it as a property in your app delegate and present the car finder on the tab controller.